# Can anyone provide what does the google-cloud-compute functions return in response?

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, cloud

It is not stated in the documentation. The docs say the request will return google.api_core.extended_operation.ExtendedOperation object. But does not state what is this and its description.

ref:https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/compute/latest/google.cloud.compute_v1.services.interconnect_attachments.InterconnectAttachmentsClient#google_cloud_compute_v1_services_interconnect_attachments_InterconnectAttachmentsClient_insert

Answer (score 2):

> **NOTE** Your question would benefit from additional clarity and an explanation of what you've tried. However, I agree that this is poorly documented and explained.

We know the answer to the question, the method returns:

```
google.api_core.extended_operation.ExtendedOperation
```

Googling that, the first result is [Long-running Operations](https://googleapis.dev/python/google-api-core/latest/operation.html).

Google Cloud Platform (GCP) has a notion of long-running operations ("operations") across its services for async calls. The platform surfaces most methods as REST-like calls and, as request-response, these aren't well-suited to "I'm working on it".

Operations are a solution to this problem. Many services' methods return Operations and the developer needs to (often poll) an (!) Operation endpoint to determine what the current state of the method is.

> **NOTE** My sense (and I may be wrong) is that Operations are surfaced inconsistently. I expect a single "Operations" service in the platform but, in reality, services that require operations, provide methods to interact with Operations. But, because Operations are used across the platform, they're defined once (as core functionality) by the libraries.

The way, I'd try to solve this is to:

1. Always start with Google's [APIs Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer).
2. Filter by the service (`compute` there are 2 versions [`v1`](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1) and [`beta`](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/beta))
3. Find the method [`interconnectAttachments:insert`](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/interconnectAttachments/insert).

Checking the [Response](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/interconnectAttachments/insert#response-body) provides more details including a link to [Handling API responses](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/api/how-tos/api-requests-responses#handling_api_responses) which provides a reasonable explanation.

I cannot confirm because I haven't (yet) tried(!):

1. Whether the Python library for Compute Engine includes methods|types for Operations or whether you should use [Operations](https://googleapis.dev/python/google-api-core/latest/operation.html) in the Core library
2. Why the Core library does not reference `ExtendedOperation`

Another trick is that `gcloud` commands can **always** be flagged `--log-http` to see the underlying calls. `gcloud compute` includes an `operations` sub-resource with [`list`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/operations/list) and `describe` commands. You can use the following to enumerate the Compute Engine related (and only Compute Engine) Operations in a project:

```bash
gcloud compute operations list \
--project=${PROJECT} \
--log-http
```

> **NOTE** This also surfaces the inconsistency in long-running Operations because ideally this would be `gcloud operations` but there is no `gcloud operations` command (even though Operations are a cross-platform resource) and the errors shows us (some) other services where Operations are used:
>
> ```bash
> gcloud operations
> ERROR: (gcloud) Invalid choice: 'operations'.
> Maybe you meant:
>   gcloud compute operations describe
>   gcloud compute operations list
>   gcloud active-directory operations cancel
>   gcloud active-directory operations describe
>   gcloud active-directory operations list
>   gcloud ai operations describe
>   gcloud ai-platform operations cancel
>   gcloud ai-platform operations describe
>   gcloud ai-platform operations list
>   gcloud ai-platform operations wait
> ```